# RStudio doesn't recognize project git repos when project is on a separate network drive

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I do most of my R coding on a secure server that I remote into. My project and package folders used to be stored on this server, but are now stored on a separate network drive that the remote server can access. I can open projects/packages, load data, run code, etc. over the network without a problem, and these projects and packages are all version-controlled with git (I set them up that way when they were stored on the local drive, before they were later moved to the separate network drive).

Here's my problem: When I open RStudio projects/packages stored on the network drive, the git menu doesn't appear. When I select Tools-->Version Control-->Project Setup, the "Version Control System" is set to "(None)". If I select "Git" from the dropdown, RStudio asks if I want to initialize a new repository for the project (even though a repository already exists in the project folder). If I select "Yes" I get an "Incorrect Function" error.

Is there some way I can get RStudio to recognize and use the existing git repo over the network as it normally would on a local drive?

In case it might be important to know:

- From the server I remote into, the network drive project folders look like this: "//securefiles/department/Joel/projects/myanalysis" (which is how RStudio "sees" the network), but the network drive is also mapped to a logical drive like "Z:/department/Joel/projects/myanalysis" on the server.
- The server is running R 4.0.4 and RStudio 1.4.1106
- The Server operating system is MS Windows Server 2016 Standard

I posted this question on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-doesnt-recognize-project-git-repos-when-project-is-on-a-separate-network-drive/100081) a week ago, but haven't gotten any answers, so I'm trying here.

**Edit:**

Following up on @Gowachin's comment, in the RStudio terminal tab for a project I ran `git status` and got the following output:

```
$ git status
Refresh index: 100% (37/37), done.
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ...[snipped]

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .Rbuildignore
        ...[snipped]

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So, it looks like I could use git from the command line, but it would be nice to find a way to use RStudio's git interface for convenience.

Comment: Hi, can you use git in command line outside of Rstudio when you are connected to the server and in this folder ?

Comment: @Gowachin I haven't tried, but possibly. Can you suggest specific commands I should run? I might even be able to do this from the terminal within RStudio.

Comment: I should try `git status` just to test if there is a repo in the folder. After this, you can use `git commit -m 'test' file` with a random file (modify a space or something useless) to test if you can commit.

Comment: The command line worked. Still, it would be nice to find a way to get the RStudio git interface back for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

We've managed to get GIT integration to work with R Studio in Windows for projects on network folders by changing the owner of the project folder (not the R Project file) to the current user of the R Project.

The first step was to access the project via a mapped drive in Windows, not via the network path. This enabled the original creator of the project to work with GIT integration. When the rest of the team did not get GIT integration on that project, that pointed to an ownership problem.

So, in a second step the user that created the project in R Studio (with GIT integration) granted everyone full access to the project folder in Windows File Explorer (Folder Properties\ Security). This enables everyone in the team to claim ownership of the folder (Folder Properties\ Security\ Advanced ...\ Owner: XYZ (Change)) when they want to interact with the repository through R Studio.

If this behaviour is not on purpose, it should be changed in/ by R Studio, I think...